# Discrepancy displaying product details - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been testing migrating new columns to my rails project. They should, ideally, display product info. However, when I select the sample product for details (show), the first three fields will display their info (description, image url, color), but not the clothing type or team name.

I don't think it's a migration issue, since those fields show their data properly in the product listing page, and the edit product form, and they are using the same ERB instance variable. (ex. they will show the team name in the products list but not viewing the product in detail)

Here's my show page. I don't see any console errors. I've checked my params, and they're fine, and like I said, the information is showing fine elsewhere. Thoughts? Thank you

```html
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @product.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @product.description %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Image url:</strong>
  <%= @product.image_url %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Color:</strong>
  <%= @product.color %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Clothing Type</strong>
  <% @product.clothing_type %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Team Name</strong>
  <% @product.team_name %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(@product) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', products_path %>
```

(edit: manners)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put `=` sign to your ruby code. Like this `<%=`, if you want to display the result.

Comment: Oh wow, I know this. I'm sorry. I've been looking at this for two days lol. Can't believe I missed this.. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You forget the `=` sign in your embedded ruby code, `<%=` You need it if you want to insert content into the web page.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to blame lack of sleep on missing that lol. Appreciate the response.